# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type asp.net core2.0 angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to simply display a table from database using Visual Studio 2017 code 2.0 with angular using WebApi, but I'm getting the error which says:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

So the steps I'm following after opening a project in Visual studio 2017 core 2.0 with Angular are:

1. Open package manager console and write these 3 commands:

   (1)`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

   (2)`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

   (3)`Scaffold-DbContext "ConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables tbbook`

This creates a Models folder with 2 class files inside it
model folder with classes

[image]

2. Then I create api controller class in controller folder as 
   `bookController.cs` and its code is as shown in image`

   [image]
3. Then I add folder named services in ClientApp>App>services, and inside
    it I create a file named `bookservice.service.ts`, the code inside it is

   [image]
4. then in CLientApp>App> i create a folder named fetchbooks and inside it 
   2 files as `fetchbooks.component.ts` and `fetchbooks.component.html`
   code inside ts file is

   [image]

   and in html file;

   [image]
5. Now in `app.shared.module.ts` file the following code is added:

   [image]

Now when I run the html file it shows me the error of inapproriate loader, Any help will be greatly appreciated plz help

Comment: Also now I managed to get rid of that error somehow, but now also im unable to get my table data being displayed, now if i open my web api data in json  it is displayed but then if i try to open any other page it shows a blank page with just "values" text written in it, and then if i try to go back to the home page at which the app lands when I first run the program it also shows the same"values" text.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it was such that, in my interface declaration I was giving one less field as compared to the data in my table which I was retrieving, just adding a new field with same fields as my table in database made it work